# Why do I need to apply DiscretizeRegion to a derived region to visualize it?

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

What are the design principles, or other explanations, as to why one needs to apply `DiscretizeRegion` to obtain a graphical representation of a derived region, rather than `Graphics` or `Graphics3D`? (It's not what I expected.)

For example, `Disk[{0,0}, 1]` and `Disk[{2,0},1]` are displayed if you wrap each in `Graphics`. Why must one then use

```
DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[Disk[{0,0}, 1], Disk[{2,0}, 1]]]
```

rather than the corresponding expression with `Graphics` instead of `DiscretizeRegion`.

The same issue arises with derived regions that are 3-dimensional, where one might expect to display them with `Graphics3D` but in fact must use `DiscretizeRegion` again.

Comment: A derived region cannot always be represented in terms of `Graphics(3D)` primitives. It can, however, be visualized with `RegionPlot(3D)`. On the other hand, mesh regions always can, so they typeset as graphics by default.

Comment: That's a question I also was curious about. @ilian could you possibly explain this in more details, to understand, why it "cannot always be represented..." ? May be you could formulate it then as a regular answer?

Comment: @Alexei Posted slightly expanded comment as an attempted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ilian pointed out in a comment, you are not limited to `DiscretizeRegion` for visualizing a region. There is also `RegionPlot`, which may be more to your liking.

Comapare

```
r = RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{2, 0}, 1]];
DiscretizeRegion[r]
```

[image: mesh]

with

```
RegionPlot[r, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Still the whole situation doesn't yet fit together for me: Using `RegionPlot` to visualize `RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{2, 0}, 1]]` makes perfect sense. However, `RegionProduct[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Line[{{0}, {1}}]]` has head `Cylinder`, so just `Graphics3D[RegionProduct[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Line[{{0}, {1}}]]]` works to see it. And `RegionProduct[Disk[], Line[{{0}, {1}}]]` has head `Cylinder`, but wrapping that with `Graphics3D` fails to display it whereas wrapping it with `RegionPlot3D` does display it.

Comment: @murray Yes, that's an inconsistency. `RegionProduct[Disk[], Line[{{0}, {1}}]]` *could* (and probably will, in a future version) autosimplify to a `Cylinder`. But it is a perfectly valid region even with head `RegionProduct`.

Comment: My personal opinion is that people use `DiscretizeRegion` way too much as an expression for visualizing regions. `RegionPlot` is really the way to go; discretization has a side effect of producing something visual, but it is really ought to be used when actual discretized property of a region approximation itself is the goal.

Sadly both of these functions have had some problems, among others consistently crashing the kernel on particularly nasty inputs. I have to check out if the situation has improved with v10.2.

Answer (score 5):

[`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) (and [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)) accept graphics primitives as input. Version 10 introduced a number of special (or basic) geometric [regions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricSpecialRegions.html) which serve as both regions and graphics primitives, so they can be given directly to `Graphics` (at least the 2D and 3D cases), for example `Graphics[Disk[]]`.

When it comes to derived regions, sometimes they directly correspond to a primitive, for example

```
RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{0, 0}], Rectangle[{0.5, 0.5}]]

(* Rectangle[{0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1} *)]
```

and thus can be fed to `Graphics` (by the way, a number of similar region autosimplification rules are under development). However, there isn't a graphics primitive corresponding to

```
RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 1]]
```

or, the equivalent region in different form

```
RegionIntersection[
  ParametricRegion[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {{r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}}], 
  ImplicitRegion[(x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2 <= 1, {x, y}]]
```

Besides boolean operations, there are other ways to construct derived regions, for example [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html) where the result generally is not going to be representable as a combination of graphics primitives.

On the other hand, a [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html) is built from cells which *are* graphics primitives and thus can always be drawn. The default is for mesh regions to typeset as graphics, which is why the result of

```
DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 1]]]
```

is immediately visualized. In the next example, the intersection is again a (boundary) mesh region and is displayed accordingly

```
mr1 = MeshRegion[{{0, 4}, {2, 1}, {4, 4}}, Polygon[{1, 2, 3}]];
mr2 = MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {2, 3}, {4, 0}}, Polygon[{1, 3, 2}]];
ℛ = RegionIntersection[mr1, mr2]
```

where the actual `Graphics` expression used by the typesetting can be shown by

```
Show[ℛ] // InputForm
```

Comment: But why `DiscretizeRegion` rather than `RegionPlot` in these two-dimensional examples?